# What is the meaning of $g(U_x) ?$

Tags: algebraic-topology, fundamental-groups

I have  some confusion  on the  definition of  discontinuous action

I found the definition on [nlab](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/properly+discontinuous+action#:%7E:text=Definition,-The%20action%20of&text=This%20is%20equivalent%20to%20the,covering%20space%20actions%20(Hatcher).)

It is written that

> The action  of  a  topological  group  $G$ on a  topological  space  $X $ is called properly  discontinious  if  every point $x \in X$  has  a  nbd $U_x$  such that  the intersection $g(U_x) \cap U_x$  with  its  translate  under the group action via  some element  $g \in G$  is  nonempty  only  for the neutral element $e \in G$

> $g(U_x) \cap U_x \neq \emptyset \implies g=e$

**My confusion** :  What  is the  meaning of $g(U_x) ?$

**My thinking** : I think $g(U_x) $  is  a  function.I think it is  a identity  fucntion $g(U_x)=U_x$

But  here  im not  getting why $g(U_x)=U_x$ become identity function ?

Comment: It means $\{ gu : u \in U_x \}$.

Comment: okay @QiaochuYuan thanks you